# spaces in path name cause problems when piping output into "find"

Tags: windows, cmd

Unable to test for the output of a program using %var% when path has spaces or uses variables
Tried the following script, only the last one worked (number of tasks was "0")

```
SET MYTEST1="C:\Program Files\Boinc\"
SET MYTEST2="C:\Progra~1\Boinc\"

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%MYTEST1%boinccmd.exe --get_tasks ^| find /i /c "executing"`) DO (
SET NumMasterTasks=%%F
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%MYTEST2%boinccmd.exe --get_tasks ^| find /i /c "executing"`) DO (
SET NumMasterTasks=%%F
)

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`C:\Program Files\boinc\boinccmd.exe --get_tasks ^| find /i /c "executing"`) DO (
SET NumMasterTasks=%%F
)


FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`C:\Progra~1\Boinc\boinccmd.exe --get_tasks ^| find /i /c "executing"`) DO (
SET NumMasterTasks=%%F
)
```

here is the output:

```
C:\Program Files\BOINC>SET MYTEST1="C:\Program Files\Boinc\"
C:\Program Files\BOINC>SET MYTEST2="C:\Progra~1\Boinc\"

C:\Program Files\BOINC>FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`"C:\Program Files\Boinc\"boinccmd.exe --get_tasks | find /i /c "executing"`) DO (SET NumMasterTasks=%F )
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\BOINC>FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`"C:\Progra~1\Boinc\"boinccmd.exe --get_tasks | find /i /c "executing"`) DO (SET NumMasterTasks=%F )
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Program Files\BOINC>FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`C:\Program Files\boinc\boinccmd.exe --get_tasks | find /i /c "executing"`) DO (SET NumMasterTasks=%F )
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files\BOINC>FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`C:\Progra~1\Boinc\boinccmd.exe --get_tasks | find /i /c "executing"`) DO (SET NumMasterTasks=%F )

C:\Program Files\BOINC>(SET NumMasterTasks=0 )
```

There are two problems with the one that works:
I want to use variables for paths and not hard code paths and,
inconveniently, "Program Files" is not always "Progra~1" as in

```
 Directory of Y:\

11/04/2019  10:12 AM    <DIR>                       .
11/04/2019  10:11 AM    <DIR>                       ..
11/04/2019  10:11 AM    <DIR>          PL6FPL~Q     Program Files
11/04/2019  10:12 AM    <DIR>          PT8A6Y~T     Program Files (x86)
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  4,778,356,477,952 bytes free
```

Tried the following (Thanks Stephan!)

```
SET "ROOTBIN=C:\Progra~1\boinc\"
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%ROOTBIN%boinccmd.exe --get_tasks ^| find /i /c "executing"`) DO (
SET NumMasterTasks=%%F
)
```

however, I used the short name for Program Files and the script will fail if I use the name with that space.

```
C:\Program Files\BOINC>SET "ROOTBIN=C:\Progra~1\boinc\"

C:\Program Files\BOINC>FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`C:\Progra~1\boinc\boinccmd.exe --get_tasks | find /i /c "executing"`) DO (SET NumMasterTasks=%F )

C:\Program Files\BOINC>(SET NumMasterTasks=30 )
```

Comment: use the correct quoting: don't `"c:\path\"program.exe`, but `"c:\path\program.exe"`

Comment: I done see how to do that using variables for paths.  SET ROOTBIN=C:\PROGRAM FILES\BOINC causes problems if the quote is left off.  Maybe there is a way to expand the variable so it includes the "find" with all the correct quotes

Comment: use `SET "MYTEST1=C:\Program Files\Boinc\"` (note the position of the quotes. They become NOT part of the value). Later use `"%MYTEST1%boinccmd.exe"

Comment: That worked for "%ROOTBIN%\boinccmd.exe" --get_tasks but not for the find.  Going to edit my post to show addition info derived from your suggeston

Comment: My error - I did not use backtick, hard to tell them apart from single apostrophy.  Going to correct my post

Comment: Still cannot get it work with a space in the path name but using the short name for paths is a work around as long as source not on NAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a folder- or file name, the *complete construct* has to be quoted.
When you use variables, best practice is to use the recommended syntax `set "var=value"`. The quotes ensure that all that belongs together, stays together. (As an additional benefit, it also works with "poison chars" (like `&<>`) without needing to escape them).
With this syntax, the quotes are *not* part of the value, so you have to quote the string later (this ensures, you have complete control of what to quote later in the code)

The removal of the trailing `\` with the path is just personal preference - I find the code to be better readable (`"%ROOTBIN%boinccmd.exe"` vs. `"%ROOTBIN%\boinccmd.exe"`)

You don't really need `usebackq` here when using the right quotes. Also `tokens=*` isn't needed here, because `| find /c` returns just a number without any spaces or other text.

Due to the piping, things change a bit. The following code should work (using `... in ('" "command"|command "') do ...` instead of trying to escape the correct parts):

```
SET "ROOTBIN=C:\Program Files\Boinc"
FOR /F %%F IN ('" "%ROOTBIN%\boinccmd.exe" --get_tasks | find /i /c "executing" "') DO (
    SET NumMasterTasks=%%F
)
echo %NumMasterTasks%
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.  I could have simplified things a bit by storing results in a file an using SET /p to get them back in but I wanted to avoid writing to the drive.  I am still confused about why short names in windows are different depending on whether on NAS or local storage but that is a non-problem now.

Comment: Short names are generated by Windows (for each new file), so they are not reliable. They merely exist for compatibility reasons with old 16-bit/8-bit programs. (not that they would run in a 64-bit environment...)